# Test package does not read Kotlin classes defined in main package

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I cannot seem to access main classes within the test package in my Kotlin module within an Android Studio project. Please note that all code shown below is within a Kotlin JVM module that is imported into the Android app.

Here's my `src/main/java` code:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Customer(val password1: String,
                val password2: String,
                @SerializedName("last_name") val lastName: String,
                @SerializedName("first_name") val firstName: String,
                val email: String)
```

My test code in `src/test/java`:

```
class CreateUser {

    @Test
    fun createRandomUser() {
        val random = Random()
        val randomNumber = random.nextInt(10000000)
        val customer = Customer("password", "password", "lastName", "firstName", "ted$randomNumber@gmail.com")

    }
}
```

My `build.gradle` code looks like the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // some other compile dependencies
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.6"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.6"
    }
}
```

The root `build.gradle` file looks as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username authToken }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    versionName = "0.1.1"
    rxJavaVersion = "2.1.3"
    okHttpVersion = "3.9.0"
    retrofitVersion = "2.3.0"
    rxJava2AdapterVersion = "1.0.0"
    googleGsonVersion = "2.8.0"
}
```

The error I get is that gradle cannot resolve `Customer` (`Unresolved reference: Customer`) in the Test class. It doesn't seem to include main classes into the test source directory. Yet, it resolves in the IDE.

Comment: Why don't you define it in `src/main/kotlin` and `src/test/kotlin` respectively?

Comment: Would that make a difference tho? @Opal

Comment: From gradle point of view it may. Gradle uses java compiler to compile java files and kotlin compiler to compile kotlin files. If kotlin files are misplaced they might not be picked for compilation, hence not found.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it

Comment: Have a look at the working demo: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46490063

Comment: yeah i saw that - i think it must be because this is a JVM module within an Android studio project

Comment: This might be the case. Tag your question with _android_ and prepare a good example.

Comment: Did you imported the Customer class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution. It seems I have to specify the src folders explicitly in my build.gradle and put all Kotlin code in `src/main/kotlin` and `src/test/kotlin` respectively.

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/main/kotlin', 'src/main/java']
    main.java.srcDirs = []
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/test/kotlin', 'src/test/java']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/kotlin', 'src/test/java']
}
```

Once I did that, the tests started to work as expected - reports are even generated on Jenkins which is great.

Comment: This answer generates: "Could not get unknown property 'kotlin' for source set main of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet."

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a sticking point for adding other JVM languages. If you added Scala to this project you would do the same thing: scala.srcDirs = ['src/main/scala', 'src/main/java']

Comment: One thing to be mindful of -- once you have gotten the gradle build dependencies sorted out, be sure and check that you're actually importing the class in question! That vexed me for several minutes.

Comment: This approach is supported by the documentation on kotlinlang: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm  "The default convention is using different folders...The corresponding sourceSets property should be updated if not using the default convention"